# <_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSP__$ 0x281131d70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key status.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutabledictionary, xcode11

my project have objective code and swift.
i found this issue in objective-c class. how to solve this?
Objective C

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableDictionary *data;
```

```
 [data setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"status"];
```

it's work fine on swift4, Xcode 10.1
but it crash and got this error on swift 5, Xcode 11

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSP__$ 0x281131d70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key status.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x21b520518 0x21a6fb9f8 0x21b43dec0 0x21bea5a00 0x102912e9c 0x102abd440 0x103c12050 0x1033dab34 0x103f208b8 0x108e3f63c 0x108df6e6c 0x10e21f6f0 0x10e220c74 0x10e22e6fc 0x21b4b1ec0 0x21b4acdf8 0x21b4ac354 0x21d6ac79c 0x24791fb68 0x1028aee4c 0x21af728e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaugh

Comment: Do you really need KVC? How about the modern and simple syntax `data[@"status"] = @3;` And the error message is about `card_status` not `status`.

Comment: @vadian i'm sorry, what it mean "KVC"? 
i use that in objective c class. i have some legacy code.

Comment: If you don't know what KVC (key-value coding) is don't use it anyway. 

Comment: oh, KVC is key-value. and can you explain me a bit for this issue?

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/

Comment: sorry about card_status not status. i change a bit after that.

Comment: data[@"status"] = @3; still got same error.

Comment: Then the error occurs somewhere else. And according to the message it's related to some bridging to Swift.

Comment: i'm pass that data from swift class to objective c view and i want to update current state in current value.

Comment: @vadian do you known how to fix it?

Comment: No, the information is too broad.